# magento-cloud: Authentication is required. Unable to login via browser

Tags: magento2, magento-cloud

I'm encountering an issue while trying to log in via my web browser. When I attempt to sign in, I'm presented with the following screen:

Login Screen Error
[image: Error]

I'm also looking for guidance on how to completely remove Magento Cloud from my system. Could someone provide a step-by-step command or instructions for uninstalling Magento Cloud? I want to ensure it's completely removed from my environment.

Any help with these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may log in to the account with:**

- An existing Adobe corporate/personal account.
- If you do not have an Adobe account, create one with the same email address.
  For steps refer to Commerce Identity Manager in Adobe Experience League.

**Please Refer Below Link** : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/unable-to-log-in-to-support-or-cloud-project.html?lang=en